# Is super saiyan god a "super saiyan" transformation, or does just it have a missleading name?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

After watching the trailer of the new Dragon Ball movie, where a villain with an armor similar to saiyans appear and it has yellow eyes,

[image]

I started to wonder if a super saiyan transformation can have eyes of a different color than blue, so I started to check,

SSJ1, USSJ, SSJ2, SSJ3, blue eyes,
SS Rage, blue eyes,
Legendary SS , blue eyes,
SS Blue, blue eyes,
SS Blue evolution, blue eyes,

SS Rosé, pink eyes, but I'm not sure if this counts because it comes from a half god / half saiyan,
Ultra Instinct grey eyes, but apparently this isnt a super saiyan transformation, but a form any race can get,
SSJ4 yellow eyes but it's non canon,

And the only one that's left is super saiyan god with red eyes, but is this transformation a real "super saiyan" transformation or it's just a missleading name? Super Saiyan Blue is attained by "getting the power of a super saiyan god and transforming into a super saiyan" . So how can you transform into a super saiyan if you already have the power of a "super saiyan" god? Wouldnt this mean the "super saiyan" god is a missleading name and it isnt a "super saiyan" transformation but another kind of saiyan transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Super Saiyan God transformation [requires the power of 6 pure hearted Saiyans](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_God#The_Ritual). However it is not mentioned anywhere that the 6 Saiyans must be Super-Saiyan themselves, (since Videl's unborn child was able to contribute as well).

I think it gets very confusing though because all the Saiyans during the ritual including Goku were super-Saiyans(except Videl's child) and yet [Videl's hair-color also changed to Golden](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonball/images/4/40/Ritual_2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20160716144138). So I think the name ***Super Saiyan God*** is a misnomer and it should have actually been ***Saiyan God***.

It would also make sense that way, since [Super Saiyan Blue](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Blue) would then technically be a **"Saiyan God"** who does a Super-Saiyan transformation. That would be more accurate, but I guess we have to accept Akira Toriyama's naming convention, since it is his creation after all.

Comment: I think you meant Videl instead of Bulma

Comment: @gl_prout Corrected. Thanks for pointing out. Totally missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question honestly doesn't make much sense as it kind of answers itself in your last paragraph, however, I'll try my best to break it down.

The color of the eyes have nothing to do with the transformations. It is just a selective form of artwork chosen by the artists of the show to help accentuate the color of the entire transformation. So In other words, *"can a super saiyan transformation have eyes of a different color than blue?"* The answer would be  **Depends**. If the artist chooses to color the eyes Orange, they'd be orange and same goes for blue.

Secondy, Super Saiyan God is indeed a Saiyan transformation. It is a form of Ritual which allows a Saiyan to attain Godly ki without actual training in the same. Goku was able to attain this transformation without any training of God Ki. We also know that this transformation can be attained by training based on Vegeta in the manga. Super Saiyan Blue, on the other hand, is the adaptation of God ki to the Super Saiyan transformation.

A good analogy for the same would be a technique like **Instant transmission**. When Goku learned the transformation, he managed to adapt it to his fighting style while he is a Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan 2 or Super Saiyan Blue etc. Similarly, when God Ki is applied during a Super Saiyan transformation, it results in a character transforming into Super Saiyan Blue. One can only do the same if he has a fairly good mastery of God Ki, which is probably why this transformation is stronger than Super Saiyan God as one can attain that even without actual training.

Also, Goku's Ulra Instinct transformation is definitely exclusive to Saiyans. The angels don't have an exclusive transformation to utilize this skill. We see Beerus utilize an unmastered version of the same in the manga. We know that the Saiyans evolution in strength is always seen through transformations. So it only makes sense this would be a transformation when a Saiyan masters it.